# Example of germs not involving series

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

note: moved from mathoverflow, as off topic.

I'm currently reading this book: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781441973993
And when speaking about germs of functions the only example provided of two functions having the same germ was a function and its Taylor expansion...

**Is there any example of two functions (f,g) having same germ at point p without one being defined as a series converging to the other?**

Indeed, the only examples I could think about where all such that:

$$ g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_i b_i(x) $$

while

$$ \lim_{i \to \infty}\sum_{i} c_i b_i(x) = f(x)$$

for some appropriate basis of the appropriate Hilbert space ( so Taylor or Fourier Series for example ).

It seems a pretty useless definition to me! As g and f are basically the same function within the disc of convergence of the series. But I'm sure I'm missing the point.

**If there is no such example then what is the point of this definition ?**

Comment: You can remove the link to MO, as you have deleted your question there (which was a good action).

Comment: Done. I thought people with high reputation score would still see it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes, people with high reputation score on MO will, but that's not very relevant here. Anyway, a silly example: $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x \in [-1,1]$, $g(x)=1$ for $x > 1$ and $g(x)=-1$ for $x<-1$. These functions surely have the same germ at $0$, for instance. Germs of function are meant to capture the behavior of functions locally, so you look only at the functions around a given point.

Comment: Humm. I understand I guess... It is actually meant to just say "this two functions are actually the same and interchangeable within some neighborhood", so example will always involve this type of switch statement you did or a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly example: $f(x)=x$ and 
$$g(x)= \begin{cases} x & x \in [-1,1]\\
 1 & x > 1 \\
-1 & x<-1.
\end{cases}
$$ These functions surely have the same germ at $0$, for instance. But also at any point $p \in (-1,1)$.

Germs of function are meant to capture the behavior of functions locally, so you look only at the functions around a given point. We care if the two functions coincide *locally*, but not globally.